# SharpArchitecture / Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent, s#arp

Does DomainSignature attribute create unique constrain in DB?

Does Fluent NHibernate 1.1.0.685 supports NaturalId correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Domain signature doesn't create constraints in DB.

Yes Fluent NH supports Natural ID by

```
map.NaturalId()
      .Property(x => x.Name)
      .Property(x => x.NickName);
```

syntax

Comment: In my configuration NaturalId doesn't work for Referenced objects (foreign keys).