# Fluent NHibernate NaturalId missing?

Tags: c#, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I have a very simple Mapping I'm trying to do. I'm following the NHibernate 3.0 Cookbook and I've come across an issue with the NaturalId() method missing from FluentNHibernate.dll. The book had me build this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;
using Eg.Core;

namespace Eg.FluentMappings.Mappings
{
    public class ProductMapping : ClassMap<Product>
    {
        public ProductMapping()
        {
            Id(p => p.Id)
                .GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
            DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("ProductType");
            Version(p => p.Version);
            NaturalId()
                .Not.ReadOnly()
                .Property(parentIsRequired => parentIsRequired.Name);
            Map(p => p.Description);
            Map(p => p.UnitPrice)
                .Not.Nullable();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to compile it, I get an error: The name 'NaturalId' does not exist in the current context. Am I missing another dll or something?

I've looked around and have found much. Here is a question that seems to be answered, but I'm not able to get it working using `map.NaturalId()` or `Map.NaturalId()`. [SharpArchitecture / Fluent NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489576/sharparchitecture-fluent-nhibernate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. Not sure why, but you have to use the base keyword on NaturalId(). Below is my revised class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;
using Eg.Core;

namespace Eg.FluentMappings.Mappings
{
    public class ProductMapping : ClassMap<Product>
    {
        public ProductMapping()
        {
            Id(p => p.Id)
                .GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
            DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("ProductType");
            Version(p => p.Version);
            base.NaturalId()
                .Not.ReadOnly()
                .Property(parentIsRequired => parentIsRequired.Name);
            Map(p => p.Description);
            Map(p => p.UnitPrice)
                .Not.Nullable();
        }
    }
}
```